# How to set German language for IBM Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

We tried to use Conversation in English, but were unable to find any German language options. We do not mean to use the interface in German but to actually train with the cohort in German.

Is this possible to do? Where do I set the language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watson Conversation [support the German language](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/index.html#supported-languages). You need to [configure the language in the Workspace when you create it](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/create-workspace.html).

Click to create a new workspace, then select the language for the dialog (The language of the user input the workspace will be trained to understand).

[image: workspace language setting]